# Combox showing User control instead of text MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I have a list of user controls. I want to display only one at a time in my view. To achieve this I am using ComboBox to show list of user controls. And display on of the them depending on the selected ComboBox item. I created a Custom interface ICustomInterface which has a Title property which I want to display to the user. And I implemented this on my user interfaces.

But problem is that when I run my application, instead of seeing Title text I see UserControl itself.

[image]

You can see here that whole user control is present in the combobox. What I need to do display text.

Here is the XAML code.

```
<ComboBox  Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Modules}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedModule}" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Title}"/>
```

Here is the view model.

```
public List<ICustomInterface> Modules
{
    get
    {
         return _modules; // Assume that there are some items present in this.
    }
}
```

And here is my user control whose collection I am trying to display.

```
public partial class LauncherView : UserControl, ICustomInterface
{
    public string Title { get { return "Launcher"; } }

    // User control stuff.
}
```

Comment: Title should be a part of the class whose type is your modules is then only title can be visible

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, it seems as though there is no connection between your `LauncherView` class and your `ICustomInterface` collection. @Farzi correctly commented that your `Title` property should have been declared in the `ICustomInterface` interface if you want to be able to access it from an `ICustomInterface` object.

To fix this problem, either add the `Title` property into the `ICustomInterface` interface, or change the type of your `Modules` collection to whichever type implements the `Title` property.

> Personal thoughts on your setup:

Personally, I think that having a collection of `UserControl` objects in a `ComboBox.ItemsSource` is not a good idea. You will be consuming all of the resources required for *all* of them, even though only one is being shown.

Instead of doing it that way, you could just use a collection of `string`s that represent the titles of each `UserControl` and then bind to the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` property. You could then have just one property of type `ICustomInterface` which you could update from the `SelectedItem` property when it changes.

In WPF, we generally work with data rather than UI controls. As such, an even better option would be to manipulate the view models of each view instead and display the view model in a `ContentControl`, having set up some `DataTemplates` first:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:YourViewModel}">
        <Views:YourView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

In the main view:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ViewModel}" />
```

In the main view model or code behind:

```
public ICustomInterface ViewModel
{
    get { return viewModel; }
    set { viewModel= value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ViewModel"); }
}

public string SelectedTitle
{
    get { return selectedTitle; }
    set 
    {
        selectedTitle = value; 
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedTitle");
        if (SelectedTitle == "Something") ViewModel = new SomethingViewModel();
        if (SelectedTitle == "Other") ViewModel = new OtherViewModel();
    }
}
```

Or you *could* have a collection of view models (wasting resources):

```
public string SelectedTitle
{
    get { return selectedTitle; }
    set 
    {
        selectedTitle = value; 
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedTitle");
        ViewModel = ViewModelCollection.Where(v => v.Title == SelectedTitle);
    }
}
```

I do understand that you did not ask for any of my personal thoughts and I hope that they have helped you in some way. Apologies if they were not welcome.